# What are "protected_settings" used for in a Terraform config

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have seen `protected_settings` used in a few examples and I have seen them in some Terraform documentation but I have been unable to find a good explanation as to what they are used for.

Comment: Looks like they might be an Azure concept?  Perhaps they're better documented in Azure.  Can't help you there, I'm using Terraform with AWS...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if they have additional usage, but for in the [azurerm_virtual_machine_extension](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/virtual_machine_extension.html) context they map straight to an Azure Resource Manager concept described in [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2016/02/26/arm-dsc-extension-settings/).

Quoting

> Settings vs. ProtectedSettings
>
> All of these settings will be saved in a settings text file on your VM.
>
> Properties under ‘settings’ are considered public properties because they will not be encrypted in the settings text file.
>
> Properties under ‘protectedSettings’ will be encrypted with a certificate and will not be shown in plain text in this file on your VM.